# GraphQL query displays only raw results

Tags: reactjs, typescript, graphql, gatsby

I have a GraphQL query kind of working (React, Gatsby, Typescript). But I only get browser to display raw json data (the "stringify" thing is what's correctly visible, raw json).

Whenever I try to use data bindings, I get error message "TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'ProjectTitles.edges.node')" in the browser. But not in console. What could be wrong? Here's the code:

```
    import { graphql, useStaticQuery } from "gatsby";
    import React, { Fragment } from "react";

    const ProjectList = () => {
      const ProjectTitles = useStaticQuery(graphql`
        {
          allMarkdownRemark(sort: { fields: frontmatter___title }) {
            edges {
              node {
                frontmatter {
                  title
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      `);
      return (
        <Fragment>
          <h2>Project titles</h2>
          <div>{ProjectTitles.edges.node.frontmatter.title}</div>
          {/* <div>{ProjectTitles.allMarkdownRemark.edges.node.frontmatter.title}</div> */}
          {/* <div>{ProjectTitles}</div> */}
          <pre>{JSON.stringify(ProjectTitles, null, 2)}</pre>
        </Fragment>
      );
    };

    export default ProjectList;
```

Comment: Have you tried using this approach instead? https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/page-query/#provide-data-to-the-homepage--component

Comment: By the way, you wouldn't be doing `ProjectTitles.edges.node.frontmatter.tittle` - `ProjectTitles.edges` is an array, so depending on which item you'd want to use to display the title, you'd have to use something like `ProjectTitles.edges[index].node.frontmatter.title`

Comment: In addition to the above comment, you could also map over the `ProjectTitles.edges` array before attempting to access any of the array item's child properties.

Answer (score 2):

Since edges will most likely be an array you need to access a certain item or map the whole array, e.g.

```js
{ProjectTitles.edges.map(node => (
    <div>{node.frontmatter.title}</div>
))}
```